# Parallax in angular js with groups of three

Tags: php, html, css, angularjs, parallax

I need the parallax effect for my site, and it should be like this

GroupOne with Image One

---

### 1 Data

### 2 Data

Group TWO with Image TWO

---

### 3 Data

### 4 Data

Group three with Image three

---

### 5 Data

### 6 Data

**For group one the parallax image should be different and so as the same for two and three with different images for each group**

**This process should be repeated if my array size is 12 also**

angular Code:

```
angular.forEach(response.data.liveData, function (value, key) {
        $scope.items.push(value);
    });
```

in which i'm adding the values to the items array

my data to the front end is like this :

```
    [data":[
{"id":"91","name":"ram"},
{"id":"93","name":"sampath"},
{"id":"104","name":"kunal"},
{"id":"109","name":"teja"},
{"id":"132","name":"ravi"},
{"id":"201","name":"deepa"}
]
```

My HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="item in Items| filter:filter">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-md-9">
              <h1>{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</h1>
          </div>
</div>
```

the output should be like this

91 - ram

93 - sampath

with a different parallax background

104 - kunal

109 - teja

with a different parallax background

132 - ravi

201 - deepa

with a different parallax background

Thanks every one

any help is appreciated